# How to add people to facebook ad account in business manager

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create ad account by following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account. With the help of this code I could successfully create ad account but I want to add myself as people as well but not getting any way to do this.

My ad account creation parameters are like

```
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => $this->accessToken,
'name' => $associative_arr['name'],
'currency' => $associative_arr['currency'],
'timezone_id' => $associative_arr['timezone_id'],
'end_advertiser' => $this->businessAccount,
'media_agency' => 'NONE',
'partner' => 'NONE',
'user_role' => '1001'
 );
```

and endpoint is

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/BUSINESS_ID/adaccount

I also tried updating ad account using following

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/aduser/v2.8

but no gain.

I am getting following error.

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [message] => (#10) Application does not have permission for this action
        [type] => OAuthException
        [code] => 10
        [fbtrace_id] => HyAJtY0OOMf
    )

)
```

Can anyone give me suggestions how I can ad people to my ad account using curl or PHP SDK?

Comment: Why don't you supply the error message for us?

Comment: I have edited my question and specified error in it. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Besides getting the ads_management permission, what was your app's Marketing API access level? The default access level supports up to only 5 ad account access. If you've accessed more than that via the API, you won't be able to do that on more accounts unless you apply for higher level of access. You can manage your ad account list in your app dashboard.